# Выдает ошибку while i in i <= N: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python

```
Нужно с помощью вложенных циклов посчитать суммы.
import math

N = int(input("N = "))
M = int(input("M = "))

p1 = 0
i = 1
while i in i <= N:
    p2 = 0
    j = 1
    while j in j <= M:
        p2 += ((i * i) + j) / j
    p1 += i * p2
y = p1
print("y = ", y)
```

Comment: Интересно как по-вашему должно отработать «i in i <= N»?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
while i in i <= N:
```

нужно

```
while i <= N:
#и внутри цикла
    i+=1
```

или (т.к. диапазон известен и остановки не предвидится)

```
for i in range(1,N+1):
```

Comment: я видимо с for перепутал и запутался.спасибо!